# Start rails server with http protocol instead of TCP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to ruby and rails. I'm working on windows 10. Rails server is starting on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 instead of http://localhost:3000. I'm using the following command.

```
rails server
```

Comment: I voted up your question as it's a legitimate one. I think developers could easily get confused and our rule at Stackoverflow is to help clarifying this confusion and documenting the information in a way that's easy for others to understand.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused with some basics in networks. I'll take the chance to clarify this to you.

Based on the Open Systems Interconnection model (OSI model) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

There are 7 layers to standardize the communication functions.

TCP is at `Transport layer`

> The transport layer provides the functional and procedural means of transferring variable-length data sequences from a source to a destination host, while maintaining the quality of service functions.
>
> The transport layer controls the reliability of a given link through flow control, segmentation/desegmentation, and error control. Some protocols are state- and connection-oriented. This means that the transport layer can keep track of the segments and re-transmit those that fail delivery. The transport layer also provides the acknowledgement of the successful data transmission and sends the next data if no errors occurred. The transport layer creates segments out of the message received from the application layer. Segmentation is the process of dividing a long message into smaller messages.
>
> OSI defines five classes of connection-mode transport protocols ranging from class 0 (which is also known as TP0 and provides the fewest features) to class 4 (TP4, designed for less reliable networks, similar to the Internet). Class 0 contains no error recovery, and was designed for use on network layers that provide error-free connections. Class 4 is closest to TCP, although TCP contains functions, such as the graceful close, which OSI assigns to the session layer. Also, all OSI TP connection-mode protocol classes provide expedited data and preservation of record boundaries. Detailed characteristics of TP0-4 classes are shown in the following table:

HTTP is at `Application layer`.

> The application layer is the OSI layer closest to the end user, which means both the OSI application layer and the user interact directly with the software application. This layer interacts with software applications that implement a communicating component. Such application programs fall outside the scope of the OSI model. Application-layer functions typically include identifying communication partners, determining resource availability, and synchronizing communication. When identifying communication partners, the application layer determines the identity and availability of communication partners for an application with data to transmit. The most important distinction in the application layer is the distinction between the application-entity and the application. For example, a reservation website might have two application-entities: one using HTTP to communicate with its users, and one for a remote database protocol to record reservations. Neither of these protocols have anything to do with reservations. That logic is in the application itself. The application layer per se has no means to determine the availability of resources in the network.

This means that `TCP` is not something else than `HTTP`. Basically, HTTP (Layer 7) is built on TCP/IP (Layer 4).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: ... which is an extensive and clear answer, but it does not really solve the confusion :-) Many web servers, after starting, mention the URL where the web application can be retrieved, like `http://localhost:3000`. That address can be retrieved / opened by any web browser. That Rails (or Puma in this case) mentions that it's listening to `tcp://localhost:3000` is correct... but that address cannot be opened by a browser / standard HTTP client.

Comment: This doesn't answer the spirit of the question: how do I start a rails server that responds to browser requests, and where do I find the URL that it's responding on?

Comment: What I tried to say with my answer is that a process that is listening to TCP connection (like in this case) is able to handle HTTP requests. It's just a more correct/generic way of saying we are supporting HTTP over TCP. No changes needed at all to fix anything as it will be working perfectly with standard http clients and browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When your Rails server says that it started on tcp://localhost:3000 , that actually means http://localhost:3030 , and on Windows machines you have to use http://127.0.01:3030 instead or else Windows messes it up somehow. Magic!